# querySelector is working once but i need to work in whole document

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

`document.querySelector()` is only working on first element but not working on rest elements.  I want to make it run on every element where the condition is true.

My Current Code Link : [Current Code](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ghxvel5a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` and then use a for loop to iterate through the array it produces.

Here is a working [fork](http://cssdeck.com/labs/adnhzbdk) of your code.

Comment: any progress @zsaat14